# How to add a third text view to list view elements using custom list adapter

Tags: android

I followed [this](http://www.ezzylearning.com/tutorial/customizing-android-listview-items-with-custom-arrayadapter) tutorial on how to add a header, a text view `id/txtTitle`, and an image view `id/imgIcon` to individual list elements within a list view.

I modified the tutorial code to incorporate a third text view `id/txtTitle2`, however I still only see the image view `id/imgIcon` and the original text view `id/txtTitle`. Additionally, the list view seems like it's bigger, or zoomed in. This is the result of my code modifications.

How can I fix the code so I see a the third text view without size distortion?

`activity_main.xml`

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="0dp"
    android:paddingRight="0dp"
    android:paddingTop="0dp"
    android:paddingBottom="0dp"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">


    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

`listview_item_row.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:padding="10dp">

    <ImageView android:id="@+id/imgIcon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp" />

    <TextView android:id="@+id/txtTitle"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="22dp"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp" />

    <TextView android:id="@+id/txtTitle2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="22dp"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

custom list adapter `WeatherAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Weather>`

```
public class WeatherAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Weather>{

    Context context;
    int layoutResourceId;
    Weather data[] = null;

    public WeatherAdapter(Context context, int layoutResourceId, Weather[] data) {
        super(context, layoutResourceId, data);
        this.layoutResourceId = layoutResourceId;
        this.context = context;
        this.data = data;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View row = convertView;
        WeatherHolder holder = null;

        if(row == null)
        {
            LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity)context).getLayoutInflater();
            row = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);

            holder = new WeatherHolder();
            holder.imgIcon = (ImageView)row.findViewById(R.id.imgIcon);
            holder.txtTitle = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.txtTitle);
            holder.txtTitle2 = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.txtTitle2);

            row.setTag(holder);
        }
        else
        {
            holder = (WeatherHolder)row.getTag();
        }

        Weather weather = data[position];
        holder.txtTitle2.setText(weather.title2);
        holder.txtTitle.setText(weather.title);
        holder.imgIcon.setImageResource(weather.icon);

        return row;
    }

    static class WeatherHolder
    {
        ImageView imgIcon;
        TextView txtTitle;
        TextView txtTitle2;
    }
}
```

class `Weather`

```
public class Weather {
    public int icon;
    public String title;
    public String title2;

    public Weather(){
        super();
    }

    public Weather(int icon, String title, String title2) {
        super();
        this.icon = icon;
        this.title = title;
        this.title2 = title2;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your row layout both your 2nd and 3rd text views have a width set as fill _ parent.. so in this scenario, the 2nd TextView takes up the entire width of the screen, and the 3rd TextView has no space left.. just change those attributes to wrap_content, or use weights instead..

Comment: Thanks. Had an inkling that was the problem. Any idea why I can't add a weight to the ImageView? Weights only appear to work with the TextViews.

Comment: I figured that list bit out on my own. Thanks.

Comment: You can add weights to ImageView too. It works exactly the same as with TextView. There are a couple of things you need to understand well before working with weights. If you assign weight to just one view out of two, it'll take up all the space available after the 2nd view has taken up the space that it needs. Also, it's best to set the width/height of the view to 0dp when a weight is assigned to it.